# How this if else condition works?

Tags: c, if-statement, debugging

I was working with some code where I have to debug and fix the bugs.
The example I am demonstrating is just an example so I understand what is wrong here.
From my understanding
when I check the value of if(check(input_num)) it should print 0 when it is even and 1 when it is odd. However, it is returning 1 wheh input is even and 0 when odd

```
#include <stdio.h>
int check(int num){
if (num%2 == 0){
    return 0;
}else{
    return 1;}
}

int main(){
int a;
cin>>a;
if(check(a)){
    return 0;
}else{
    return 1;}
return 0;}
```

Comment: Your first step should be giving the function a meaningful name. `check` doesn't tell you nor us anything. Name it `isEven` or `isOdd` depending on what it should return.

Comment: `return` does not print anything. It specifies the return value of a function and then exits that function. There is nothing in your code that would print output, so no output should be expected.

Comment: When your function returns 1, your program returns 0, and vice versa. How that makes any sense, nobody knows.

Comment: `cin >>` is not C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C, `0` is considered `false` and all non-zero values are considered `true`.

So, in your `main` function, the `if` statement evaluates to `true` when the function returns `1` (a non-zero value) and to `false` when it returns `0`.

So in `main` you're returning `0` when `check` returned `1` and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

Your function  `int check(int num)` is returning the correct value, but in the `main()` since you are again using `if(check(a)` again it takes the output of your function `int check(int num)` as input  **1** and `return 0` and **0** as input `return 1`.

It should be like this-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

int check(int num) {
    if (num%2 == 0){
        return 0; } 
 else{
    return 1;}
    }

int main() { 
  int a; 
  cin>>a; 
  cout<<check(a); }
```